# SQL Server Management Studio description on foreignkey weirdness

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

In [SQL Server Management Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) we enter a description for a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) in this dialog (modify on foreign key from table `Campus`):

[image: SQL Server Management Studio dialog]

As you can see, the description seems to be emtpy.

However, if I run this query:

```
select object_name([major_id]), [ep].[name], [value]
from sys.extended_properties ep
INNER join sys.objects o on o.object_id = major_id
where o.[type] = 'F'
```

the result is:

```
FK_Campus_School    MS_Description  foobar
```

If I enter a text in the description field (because I think the field is not yet set) I overwrite the original value.

I know I can use this stored procedure to add/update extended properties from a script:

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty /* sp_updateextendedproperty */
@name = N'MS_Description', 
@value = N'is this saved again?', 
@level0type = N'SCHEMA', 
@level0name = N'Data', 
@level1type = N'TABLE', 
@level1name = N'Campus',
@level2type = N'CONSTRAINT', 
@level2name = N'FK_Campus_School';
```

Notice that calling `sp_addextendedproperty` does raise an exception if the property is already defined. The dialog seems to always do an update.

**What have I tried**

The text is shown if I open the foreign key dialog on the referenced table. That dialog show the FK_Campus_School key as well, and after selecting that one, the description is shown. Going back to the Campus table the foreign key description is then shown. However, after executing a single query I'm in the same boat again.

Hitting the Refresh button and/or context menu option didn't resolve this.

**Is there anything else I can do to have SQL Server Management Studio show the description reliably in the foreign key modify dialog?**

Version information:

```
| Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  | 10.50.1617.0
| Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) | 6.1.7601.17514
| Microsoft MSXML                         | 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
| Microsoft Internet ExploreR             | 8.0.7601.17514
| Microsoft .NET Framework                | 2.0.50727.5472
| Operating SysteM                        | 6.1.7601
```

Target: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Have you tried to see if it displays correctly with different version of SSMS? Perhaps SSMS - 2012? Have you updated SSMS 2008 R2 since then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must refresh your IntelliSense:

- In SQL Server Management Studio, menu *Edit* -> *IntelliSense* -> *Refresh Local Cache*

OR

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>

It's working in SQL Server 2012. I also tested my solution in SQL Server 2008 R2, but it does not work.